# Best practice for batch UPDATE operations

Tags: rest, crud

For my application, I would like to have my CREATE and UPDATE endpoints support both single and batch insertions/updates.

I know that typically the standard for these URIs would be `/{resource}` for POST, and `/{resource}/{id}` for PUT.

The POST endpoint would work fine for batch operations. It would just involve a simple check if the received data is in an array format or not. For PUT however, this wouldn't work, as the URI requires an id for the specified resource.

I could change the PUT URI to just `/{resource}` but is this a bad practice? Is it better to instead have separate endpoints for single and batch operations, for both CREATE and UPDATE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CRUD is the backbone of rest

1. Create - to have a whole new resource structure ( batch almost always)
   via POST/{resource} -- only batch no filters
2. Retrieve - selecting created resource per id/batch can be both via
   GET/{resource} or GET/{resource}/{id}
   need to have both
3. Update - updating mostly by ids filter 
   PUT/{resource}/{id} can have via filter mainly
4. Delete - deleting again whole batch/ids
   Delete/{resource} or Delete/{resource}/{id}
   Need to have both

So, Its similar to a `where` clause at `Rest's` end except for create. You need to have seperate end points for ease in usage as Rest Apis serve data mainly and no ModelAndView structural pages. Hence, keeping seperate endpoint for each is a better practice